# Emails sent from group mailbox do not appear in the mailbox's sent folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, office365, shared-mailbox

Was just presented with a question from one of the sysadmins at my company.

Environment: Office 365 Exchange in the cloud.

Workstations:

- Windows 7 Enterprise x64 with Outlook 2010
- macOS 10.10-12 using Outlook 2011 or 2016.

Situation: There is a shared mailbox that 5-6 users access on a daily basis and send emails out of. Users can access the mailbox either via their own Outlook clients if provided access prior or through our OWA site.

Currently when an email is sent, a copy is created in the user's Sent folder. What we'd like to do is to have the copy added to the Sent folder of the shared mailbox itself.

Is this something that can be accomplished? The sysadmin mentioned that he remembered hearing about some kind of a registry modification.

Note: I work in Desktop Support and do not have direct access to our email servers. any questions about back-end systems I will direct to the sysadmin in question and report back so there may be a delay in responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook 2010 supports more than one primary exchange mailboxes.

In order for this to work, you need to manually add the mailboxes in exchange. This way, all settings regarding to the mailbox are kept for the mailbox.

This means, that if you give rights to a specific mailbox to a user and outlook automatically opens the mailbox, it is not loaded as primary mailbox, which is why sent items are brought to the users mailbox instead of the shared mailbox.

By manually adding the shared mailbox through the outlook profile, it will keep the sent mails in the send items folder of the shared mailbox.

## How to:

So what you need to do, is on each pc with outlook 2010, is go to *Control Panel* > *Email* and configure email to add a new mailbox. Choose to add it manually. Enter the details for the mailbox and when it asks for a username and password, use the credentials for that specific user. The server here is `outlook.office365.com`. `outlook.office.com` will also work.

When you now open outlook, you may see the mailbox 2 times. Ignore this for now, and ensure that it works. Now close outlook and open it a second time. The 2 items have now been merged to 1 and all should work as desired.

Comment: I essentially ended up doing this but in OWA. I logged the user into their mailbox and used the "Open another mailbox" option to get to their shared mailboxes. I then saved bookmarks for each mailbox to a folder.

Comment: Yeah, that is basically the same, but it works as described above in outlook too. Having it in one client can be preferable to the user.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, this feature is disabled by default in Exchange 365

From the article
[Want more control over Sent Items when using shared mailboxes?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2015/03/03/want-more-control-over-sent-items-when-using-shared-mailboxes/) :

> It can be enabled by setting feature enable flag to TRUE:
>
> **For emails Sent As the shared mailbox:**
>
> ```
> set-mailbox <mailbox name> -MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled $True
> ```
>
> **For emails Sent On Behalf of the shared mailbox:**
>
> ```
>  set-mailbox <mailbox name> -MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled $True
> ```
>
> If you then want to disable the feature again, you can do it as
>   follows:
>
> **For emails Sent As the shared mailbox:**
>
> ```
> set-mailbox <mailbox name> -MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled $False
> ```
>
> **For emails Sent On Behalf of the shared mailbox:**
>
> ```
>  set-mailbox <mailbox name> -MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled $False
> ```

Let me know if that helps.